# In LINQ to SQL, how to perform a subquery with max?

Tags: linq-to-sql, correlated-subquery

var ItemScores = (from a in response.ItemScores where a.LastUpdated ==
(from d in response.ItemScores where a.Word_Id == d.Word_Id select a.LastUpdated).Max() select a);

The above query is supposed to return only the most recent ItemScore for each Word.
Each Word can have one or more ItemScores, because multiple scorers can score the same word.
I'm trying to get a list of item scores (one per word), such that each item score is the most recent one for that word.

This query is unfortunately returning ALL item scores (multiple item scores per word), as though it's completely ignoring the LastUpdated subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
var itemScores = response.ItemScores
                         .GroupBy(x => x.Word_Id)
                         .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdated)
                                       .First());
```

Comment: Thanks LukeH.  I just realized I simply had an "a.LastUpdated" where it should have been "d.LastUpdated" in the subquery.